# Applying CSS to a form

Tags: html, css, forms

I can't get CSS to apply to the function below.  Is it because it's a form or because it uses dl, dt, and dd tags?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

    echo '<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php"> 

  <div class=\"logintitle\">Please login</div> 
  <dl class=\"usernamefield\"> 
    <dt class=\"siteadd\"><label title="Username">Username: </label></dt> 
    <dd class=\"siteadd\"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="30" id="username" /></dd> 
  </dl> 
  <dl class=\"siteadd\"> 
    <dt class=\"siteadd\"><label title="Password">Password: </label></dt> 
    <dd class=\"siteadd\"><input tabindex="2" accesskey="p" name="password" type="password" maxlength="15" id="password" /></dd> 
  </dl> 
  <ul> 
    <li><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/register.php" title="Register">Register</a></li> 
    <li><a href="http://www...com/sandbox/lostpassword.php" title="Lost Password">Lost password?</a></li> 
  </ul> 
  <p class=\"siteadd\"><input tabindex="3" accesskey="l" type="submit" name="cmdlogin" value="Login" ';
    if ($disabled == true)
    {
        echo 'disabled="disabled"';
    }
    echo ' /></p></form>';


}
```

Comment: you should check your generated html using firebug, and see from there. Let us know :-)

Comment: Not completely related to the issue, As I am pretty much alien to PHP, but is this way PHP guys code their HTML? PHP code spits complete HTML? Not HTML code has php scriptlets?

Comment: @Teja The above is quite wrong on many levels... :)

Comment: @deceze Why is it wrong?

Comment: This is why PHP gets a bad rap... :(

Comment: @John Generally speaking, mixing HTML and PHP like this gets very messy. Much better to use PHP like a templating system than echo the HTML.

Comment: @mmattax It works totally fine.  I just can't get CSS to apply to it.

Comment: @mmattax totally agree; large chunks of html should be stored in a static html/template file.
@john we still need to see your css to help you, are you getting any styling applied? is the css file actually being loaded correctly?

Comment: Your CSS is needed to see where the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an escaping error within your code. To show just an extract:

```
  echo ' ... <div class=\"logintitle\">Please login</div>  ... ';
```

You use `'` but then escape `"`, which will lead to `\"` being printed out to the user. You don't have to escape `"` when using `'` as main quotes. This could be the problem for your browser, not correctly identifying your divs and thereby not applying css.

addendum:

when echo'ing large portions (as already mentioned it would be better to use a templating system, e.g. smarty), you can close and reopen your php tags for better reading:

```
function show_loginform($disabled = false)
{

?>
<form name="login-form" id="login-form" method="post" action="./index.php"> 

  <div class="logintitle">Please login</div> 
  <dl class="usernamefield"> 
    ...
<?php
   if(true)
   {
      echo 'foobar';
   }
?>

   ...
  </p></form>
<?php

} // function end
```

and you can crash most syntax highlighters doing this btw ;)

Comment: Thanks... this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from mixing HTML and PHP in that way, your code is valid enough. I am able to apply CSS to the above exact code. The problem is in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve your problem but a tip for future programming:

It's not necessary to compare $disabled to true as $disabled is already a boolean.

```
if ($disabled == true){
    echo 'disabled="disabled"';
}
```

The following shows much more of an understanding of boolean types:

```
if ($disabled){
    echo 'disabled="disabled"';
}
```

Post your CSS and it will be much easier to help you with your original problem...